# OAuth2 Spring client error: No redirect URI has been established

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-3

I'm trying to set up a Spring OAuth2 client that authenticates to my own provider and resourceserver. Provider and resource server are one application in my case.

I have problems with setting up the OAuth client with Spring 3.2. When I call the OAuth2RestTemplate in the Controller (by getting a web page) I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No redirect URI has been established
>   for the current request.  at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:159)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:216)
>   ...

As I understand the redirect is automatically set from the current request uri. Anyway, I tried to set the *oauth:resource* attribute *pre-established-redirect-uri="http://localhost:8080/myresourcesercer/"*. Then I get this error:

> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException:
>   A redirect is required to get the users approval
>   ...

How do I set the redirect uri correctly or what am I missing?

Thanks!

Here's my config:

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

 <oauth:client id="my-client" />

<oauth:resource id="security" type="authorization_code" client-id="my-client" client-secret="secret" access-token-uri="http://localhost:8080/provider/oauth/token"
 scope="read,write" user-authorization-uri="http://localhost:8080/provider/oauth/authorize" authentication-scheme="query"/>

<bean id="fooService" class="com.mypackage.serviceImpl.FooServiceImpl">
    <property name="secureRestTemplate">
        <oauth:rest-template resource="security" />
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven>

       <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
  ...
     </mvc:message-converters> 
     </mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.serviceImpl" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>


 <bean id="viewResolver"
    class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

…

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: I figured out that the second error message was misleading. Not sure anymore what the actual problem was but you couldn't guess it from the error message. My current (and working) client configuration looks like this: `<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
  <oauth:client client-id="MYCLIENTID"
   secret="MYSECRET"
   authorized-grant-types="implicit,authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token,password" authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write" />
 </oauth:client-details-service>` Does this help you?

Comment: Which grant-type do you actually use? Do you get a request like "Would you like to grant access to ..." ? I have the same problem here and there is still no solution. Unfortunately my OAuth provider only allows the authorization_code grant.

Comment: I used both "authorization_code" and "client_credentials". When I used "authorization_code" I got the response "would you like to grant access..", yes. The client config in the comment above worked for me. Check if your request is correct. I found this page helpful to understand how the requests have to look like:[link]( http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)

Answer (score 0):

The [OAuth2ClientContextFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/OAuth2ClientContextFilter.html) will set the redirect URI for you. You could configure it manually or have Spring Security can set that up for you automatically.

If you want Spring Security to set it up then you would need changes in your [web.xml](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/ns-config.html#ns-web-xml)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And you would need an [`<http/>` block](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oAuth2#client-configuration)

Answer (score -1):

This line of code causing a problem of photos(Model model)

```
ObjectNode result = facebookRestTemplate
                .getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", ObjectNode.class);
```

It redirecting me to the Facebook page after login into it successfully its returning back with the URL like this, but seems not working afterwards...

[Check Link](http://localhost:8080/tonr2/facebook/info?code=AQD-vJQ2sFwCkBWcktEwxiFRl1RV0eP5gh648G1KKzz2wwZNUOpytj21DqR8t38NqLGnNHgjr07720KycMqhYZJtNZ-4TOgM8GeSND2KMFR1QTGRpWkU8Qjhb-FwrqzAzB2yGPhN67_MesyK7FgDKT2fDzo1yFqWzOZ8rxQbf_xc2ozF47ZBmN4UtC2mI6bX4iRkbFqXm3PQNFHXd5_0HpL8_tflAQ2fPFXn-eyuTkf_h0JP6Q-B_NPMCCUxwHQTS3FFjEWNNWcM_wo86VlBNCnPt1XDdY78OJXPbo9AlRSM3jnqZysU80K6kFn2ZWp8LffJ6bQ-AptNL7NKfbz6UhwR&state=dkKAJv#_=_)

I think something went wrong causing a problem.